# Remove the li childeren

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, children

I want remove the li that is arround this link.

I have this script.

```
$('a[href$="archief"]').children('li').remove();
```

What do i wrong? I want to select the list item that is arround the link.

Comment: Title says children, last sentence implies parent...

Comment: Can you show us an example of the HTML before and after modification?  That will ensure we understand what you want to do.

Comment: please show your HTML and clarify your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong way, `children()` searches for children, `closest()`, `parent()` and `parents()` looks for parents :

```
$('a[href$="archief"]').closest('li').remove();
```

This would of course also remove anything inside the list item.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a[href$="archief"]').unwrap();
```

Comment: which will likely end up with illegal HTML with an `<a>` directly under the `<ul>` ...

Comment: @Alnitak - Yup, and if the anchor isn't a direct child of the list item, it won't remove the list item, so it won't work either way.

Comment: @Alnitak Well uhm.. yeah. The question is a little vague since it states. `I want remove the li that is arround this link.` buy the title says `Remove the li childeren`. He probably wants to remove the `li` that contain this link, but it should be more clear. Then again if he has `a` as a parent for `li` that is invalid again.

Answer (score 1):

When it is around, you should take a look at [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).